# Updating 2 tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code so far. I am not sure what to put in the `When not matched` because in theory they should always have a match. So I guess I could put `''` (for null) in there?

Also I need a condition in my subquery for WHERE to_date(fgmulti.in_date) = to_date(sysdate).

```
MERGE INTO fgmulti FGM
USING
    (SELECT * FROM arinvt 
     WHERE class LIKE 'CP%' OR 'FG%' OR 'IN%' OR 'LA%' OR 'PK%') AS Classes
ON fgm.arinvt_id = classes.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    SET non_conform_id = '21'
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
          INSERT (non_conform_id) VALUES ('17')
```

I am not sure about your question with the SQL Fiddle since I do not think I need to create another table as I am trying to update a current one.  If I sound ridiculous, please let me know - ha!

Comment: Write two `MERGE` statements. You need to post the **create and insert statements** as we do not have your tables and data. Show your desired output. At least, create a **SQL Fiddle**.

Comment: I updated my question to (hopefully) help us go in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for Oracle.  This should work.

```
MERGE INTO fgmulti FGM
USING
    (SELECT * FROM arinvt 
     WHERE class LIKE 'CP%'
     OR  class LIKE  'FG%'
     OR  class LIKE   'IN%' 
     OR  class LIKE   'LA%' 
     OR  class LIKE   'PK%') Classes
ON (fgm.arinvt_id = classes.id
    and fgm.in_date = sysdate)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET non_conform_id = '21'
```

Note that the branches are optional.  If you don't want to do anything when the rows don't match then just omit the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause.

Also, we don't need `TO_DATE()` when that value is already a DATE, which `sysdate` certainly is and I'd hope `in_date` would be too.

Comment: Figured it out - just need to add an UPDATE statement before SET to the portion you posted.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @RyanShukis - oops! :)